# Ruby on Rails: Operation now in progress - connect(2) would block

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, actionmailer

I'm working on a site someone else made. There is a production version.

I'm trying to send emails to users whose properties haven't been updated in 30 days.

Everything works until I try to use `deliver_later`. The reason I'm using `deliver_later` is because `deliver_now` results in an issue of sending too many emails per second. I'm currently using Mailtrap for testing, but I assume I will run into that sort of issue on production.

So I opted to wait 1 second for each email:

```
      @testproperties = Property.has_not_updated.includes(:user)
      @testproperties.each do |property|
          UserMailer.with(property: property, user: property.user).check_listing.deliver_later(wait:1.seconds)
      end
```

This results in `IO::EINPROGRESSWaitWritable` `Operation now in progress - connect(2) would block`

And nothing sends.

I'm not sure how to solve this issue.

Edit:
I can see on the production site that I can visit the route /sidekiq. The routes file has this block:

```
  authenticate :user, lambda { |u| u.admin? } do
    mount Sidekiq::Web => '/sidekiq'
  end
```

I can view the web interface and see all the jobs. It's all working there. But I need to access development version running on `localhost:3000`.

Trying to access this locally still results in:

`Operation now in progress - connect(2) would block`

```
  #  # Socket#connect
  def connect_nonblock(addr, exception: true)
    __connect_nonblock(addr, exception)
  end
end
```

Sidekiq.rb:

```
require 'sidekiq'

unless Rails.env.test?
  host = 'localhost'
  port = '6379'
  namespace = 'sitename'

  Sidekiq.configure_server do |config|
    config.redis = { url: "redis://#{host}:#{port}", namespace: namespace }
    schedule_file = "config/schedule.yml"
    if File.exists?(schedule_file)
      Sidekiq::Cron::Job.load_from_hash YAML.load_file(schedule_file)
    end
    config.server_middleware do |chain|
      chain.add Sidekiq::Status::ServerMiddleware, expiration: 30.minutes
    end
    config.client_middleware do |chain|
      chain.add Sidekiq::Status::ClientMiddleware, expiration: 30.minutes
    end
  end

  Sidekiq.configure_client do |config|
    config.redis = { url: "redis://#{host}:#{port}", namespace: namespace }
    config.client_middleware do |chain|
      chain.add Sidekiq::Status::ClientMiddleware, expiration: 30.minutes
    end
  end
end
```

for cable.yml:

```
development:
  adapter: async
  url: redis://localhost:6379/1
  channel_prefix: sitename_dev

test:
  adapter: async

production:
  adapter: redis
  url: redis://localhost:6379/1
  channel_prefix: sitename_production
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The production server is running Ubuntu and they already installed `redis-server`.

I had not installed that locally. (I'm using Ubuntu through Windows WSL)

```
sudo apt install redis-server
```

I can now access the web interface.

Comment: I was in the exact same situation and this was the issue! Installed and started the redis-server service in my WSL environment and it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that Redis is started:

```
 sudo service redis-server restart
```

Comment: worked when I restarded redis